# How to implement a “rate us” feature in a phonegap app in windows phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I want to implement rate us option in phone gap for windows phone.

I am not able to redirect from explorer.

Comment: Rate us like review star ?

Comment: you can try to create a plugin with this https://github.com/nokia-developer/rate-my-app